# Publish word 2016 taskpane add-in manifest in SharePoint 2013 with commands section(VersionOverrides)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, manifest, office-addins, office-js

I am trying to develop a Word 2016 add-in and publish the manifest file to the SharePoint 2013 Add-in Catalog. I use Visual Studio 2015 and Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015 and chooses the Visual C# -> Office/SharePoint-> Web Add-ins->Word Add-in template.

If I deploy this project to the IIS and put the manifest file generated from visual studio in a network share, then it works fine and I can see the addin in word 2016 from the network share.

But if I try to put the same manifest file in the Add-in Catalog of the SharePoint 2013 in our environment, then the state of the manifest is “not valid”.  After some research I found in SharePoint logs the message “Invalid Agave manifest 'AgaveCatalog/WordWebAddInTestManifestManifest.xml': Der Typ 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0:VersionOverrides' ist nicht deklariert.”. translated: “The type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0:VersionOverrides' is not declared”

So I deleted all VersionOverrides references from the manifest and now its valid and word can see this add-in from SharePoint catalog. But this mean, I cannot use the “commands” feature in the manifest file to customize my add-in.

The Question: Is it possible to use commands(VersionOverrides) in the manifest file for word 2016 add-ins in the SharePoint 2013 Add-in catalog and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The SP Add-in catalog is not a supported method to deploy add-ins with commands. You can try the [new Admin center](https://support.office.com/en-IE/article/Deploy-Office-Add-ins-in-the-Office-365-admin-center-preview-737e8c86-be63-44d7-bf02-492fa7cd9c3f?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE) though. For future reference here is a useful [FAQ for commands](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/blob/master/FAQ.md).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and references! So looks like, under restriction, that the project has to be on-premise (without online access), I have only two options to publish manifests: network share with commands or add-in catalog without commands.